# Cannot instantiate a firefox web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am tryng to learn Selenium and am instantiating a FirefoxDriver

```
final WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("http://www.hw-group.com/products/charon2/ch2dk_demo_en.html");
```

but I get this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'alex-ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-73-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
```

and some times also this one:

```
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -ea -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=src/test/resources/chromedriver-linux -Didea.launcher.port=7540 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/alex/IntelliJ/IntelliJHome/idea-IU-145.972.3/bin -Didea.junit.sm_runner -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/alex/IntelliJ/IntelliJHome/idea-IU-145.972.3/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/alex/IntelliJ/IntelliJHome/idea-IU-145.972.3/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/java-atk-wrapper.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/alex/IntelliJ/IntelliJ-Workspace/SeleniumTutorial/target/test-classes:/home/alex/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.4/cucumber-java-1.2.4.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.4/cucumber-core-1.2.4.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-html/0.2.3/cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.5/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/info/cukes/gherkin/2.12.2/gherkin-2.12.2.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.4/cucumber-junit-1.2.4.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-server/2.53.0/selenium-server-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.48/jcommander-1.48.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/mx4j/mx4j-tools/3.0.1/mx4j-tools-3.0.1.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/jetty-repacked/9.2.13.v20150730/jetty-repacked-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/jetty-rc-repacked/5/jetty-rc-repacked-5.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/2.53.0/selenium-java-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/2.53.0/selenium-chrome-driver-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.53.0/selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/2.53.0/selenium-api-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/httpclient-4.5.1.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.3/httpcore-4.4.3.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-edge-driver/2.53.0/selenium-edge-driver-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.53.0/selenium-firefox-driver-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver/2.53.0/selenium-ie-driver-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/4.1.0/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/2.53.0/selenium-safari-driver-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.5.7.Final/netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/2.53.0/selenium-support-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-leg-rc/2.53.0/selenium-leg-rc-2.53.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.8/snakeyaml-1.8.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 WebDriverTest
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["sv-SE"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Ubuntu-paket för Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["uk"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Убунтівські доповнення до Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["zh-CN"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Ubuntu 火狐扩展包.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["zh-TW"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Ubuntu Firefox 擴充包。","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null}],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"9.0","maxVersion":"37.0a1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
1466339074988   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1466339074988   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1466339074988   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1466339074989   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1466339074989   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1466339074991   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1466339075001   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1466339075002   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1466339075007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1466339075007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1466339075007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1466339075008   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1466339075008   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1466339075008   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1466339075627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1466339075627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1466339075627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1466339075683   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1466339075683   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1466339075683   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1466339075689   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1466339075689   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1466339075691   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1466339075704   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1466339075704   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1466339075704   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1466339075708   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1466339075716   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1466339075789   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1466339075796   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at WebDriverTest.webDriverTest(WebDriverTest.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["sv-SE"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Ubuntu-paket för Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["uk"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Убунтівські доповнення до Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["zh-CN"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Ubuntu 火狐扩展包.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["zh-TW"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Ubuntu Firefox 擴充包。","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null}],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"9.0","maxVersion":"37.0a1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
1466339074988   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1466339074988   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1466339074988   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1466339074989   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1466339074989   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1466339074991   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1466339075001   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1466339075002   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1466339075007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1466339075007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1466339075007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1466339075008   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1466339075008   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1466339075008   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1466339075627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1466339075627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1466339075627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1466339075683   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1466339075683   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1466339075683   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1466339075689   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1466339075689   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1466339075691   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1466339075704   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1466339075704   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1466339075704   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1466339075708   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1466339075716   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1466339075789   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1466339075796   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'alex-ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-73-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at WebDriverTest.webDriverTest(WebDriverTest.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["sv-SE"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Ubuntu-paket för Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["uk"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Убунтівські доповнення до Firefox.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["zh-CN"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Ubuntu 火狐扩展包.","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null},{"locales":["zh-TW"],"name":"Ubuntu Modifications","description":"Ubuntu Firefox 擴充包。","creator":"Canonical Ltd.","homepageURL":null}],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"9.0","maxVersion":"37.0a1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
1466339074988   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1466339074988   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1466339074988   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1466339074989   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1466339074989   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1466339074990   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1466339074991   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1466339075001   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1466339075002   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1466339075004   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1466339075007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1466339075007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1466339075007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1466339075008   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1466339075008   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1466339075008   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1466339075627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1466339075627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1466339075627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1466339075683   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1466339075683   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1466339075683   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1466339075689   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1466339075689   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1466339075691   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1466339075704   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1466339075704   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1466339075704   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1466339075708   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1466339075716   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1466339075789   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1466339075796   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    ... 34 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I am using it with

> Firefox Version 47.0, first offered to Release channel users on June 7, 2016

on my Ubuntu Desktop.

When I use a CromeDriver:

> final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

everything works fine and I can connect to my web page

Comment: You are using a RemoteWebDriver, therefor you need a Selenium server where you connect to. But without proper code and stack description people can only guess.

Comment: I updated my description. I do not know why do I need a Selenium server. I just want to connect to a random web page from Internet using selenium. If I use a ChromeDriver with the corresponding binaries, then everything works as expected. I just do not understand why a FirefoxDriver does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded Firefox to the previous version 46.0.1 and now it works.

I just do not understand how can I use Selenium if I do not know what browser versions are compatible, because this thing is not explained anywhere...